# Can 32-bit drivers be loaded into 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: drivers, dell-vostro

I am using Windows 7 32-bit on a Dell Vostro 1014 (Intel Core 2 Duo T6670 CPU) and now I want install a 64-bit version of Windows.

My questions:

1. How can I be sure that my laptop is compatible with 64-bit Windows 7?
2. On the Dell website, I only see drivers for Windows 7 32-bit. Will Windows 7 64-bit supply its own drivers for my laptop, or will I be unable to use the 64-bit version due to the unavailability of 64-bit drivers from Dell?
3. If I try to install 32-bit drivers on Windows 7 64-bit, will the 32-bit drivers work?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You may have noticed that I have *significantly* re-written your question to be clearer and with much better grammar, capitalization, punctuation, spelling, etc. In the future, it would be appreciated if you could spend more effort making sure that your posts are legible to the reader before you post them.

Comment: You can determine if your CPU is a 64-bit by looking at the specifications for it on [Intel's website](http://ark.intel.com/products/42109/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6670-2M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB). You will be unable to install 32-bit drivers on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the required drivers from Dell website  [here](http://downloads.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/vostro-1014.html) If you are doing a clean install Windows will do most of the driver installs for you.

To answer your question you need to use to correct drivers. For a look at how these systems work I suggest you have a read from  [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: i installed 64 bit windows 7 ultimate..now wifi driver and blutooth driver not worksing..when i prompt to clik fn+f11 wifi is not working ..how to get ridd off this prblem..help me

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

> How can I be sure that my laptop is compatible with 64-bit Windows 7?

Your processor supports the "EM64T" instruction set, so at a fundamental level, it is compatible with Windows 7 64-bit. The real question is whether it will run *optimally* on 64-bit. By *optimally*, I mean, will it only run the Microsoft built-in drivers, or are there 64-bit native drivers available for the customized hardware.

> On the Dell website, I only see drivers for Windows 7 32-bit. Will Windows 7 64-bit supply its own drivers for my laptop, or will I be unable to use the 64-bit version due to the unavailability of 64-bit drivers from Dell?

As you can see from [the page linked to by Matthew Williams' answer](http://downloads.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/vostro-1014.html), it appears that 64-bit drivers *do* exist for your computer, contrary to what you said. Even without these drivers, though, Windows 7 *should* at least install and boot up to the desktop, though you may not be able to take advantage of all features/buttons or get the best graphical performance in the absence of 64-bit drivers. That's not a problem for you, though, as the drivers seem to be there.

> If I try to install 32-bit drivers on Windows 7 64-bit, will the 32-bit drivers work?

No. It is not possible to make 32-bit drivers work on a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

A. Check the Windows 7 HCL.

B1. Yes. B2. Maybe.

C. No.

Answer (score -1):

Simply? Not completely, but as long as you are on ethernet with your laptop when installing Windows 7, it should pick up the drivers automatically. Search for drivers from Dell. Once you have those, have Windows search for drivers. That processor is compatible with Windows 7 64-bit, as I've used it with it before.